# Echo Magento price minus discount

Tags: magento, echo

I am trying to echo the product price minus a discount on the product-page, based on checking the product price. The checking is working, however I can't manage to output the discounted price.

> Example: If the price is between 50 and 100, i'd like to `echo product price * 0.8 (20% discount)`

```
<?php if ($_product->getFinalPrice() >= 50 && $_product->getFinalPrice() < 100 )  : ?>
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product)*0.8 ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have tested that the rule works ok. I also manage to output only the price. But the *0.8 doesn't works (It is probably not the correct way to calculate it, but I've tried just about everything except the correct thing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you must do something like that:

```
<?php if ($_product->getFinalPrice() >= 50 && $_product->getFinalPrice() < 100 )  : ?>
<?php 
      $valWithDiscount = $this->getPriceHtml($_product)*0.8;
      echo  $valWithDiscount;
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That shoud solve your problem, let me know.

Live Long and Prosper \//

Comment: Tried this variant, but it didn't work..  Resulted in showing a zero.

Comment: doh ... mi mistake, you should use the $_product->getFinalPrice() instead of $this->getPriceHtml($_product) (this will get only html formatted), i made mi self clear ? @Espen srry Brow

Comment: Tested v2 of your code, and it worked.. Thanks for helping. -Espen

Answer (score 2):

No that wont work.  The problem is you are trying to apply a mathematical equation on a block of html.

Try this instead to express the price with the modification while maintaining the current currency character and decimal rules;

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice()*.8, true, false); ?>
```